# Android- split URL string

Tags: android, string, url, split

I have a url I would like to split, so I essentially only have "Dub-Boro - Get Down.mp3"

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/******/Week%20of%20July%2025/Dub-Boro%20-%20Get%20Down.mp3

I was thinking of doing a split, but don't know how to approach it. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] path = uri.getPath().spit("/");
String mp3 = path[ path.length - 1 ];
```

Comment: So the way I have it set up is that my url is changed to a string already. So I just need to split the string?

Comment: You can just split the string sure, but I'd keep this thing as URL.  There is utility in having it wrapped in an object.

Comment: what about doing a `string.replace()`?